# How to instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier from inside UITableViewCell Controller

Tags: uitableview, swift

The goal is to create a new view controller from inside a custom **UITableViewCell** function. All the examples I've seen do this from within a **UIVIewController**.

How should this be accomplished?

This is the full controller for the custom table nib.

```
import UIKit

class feedRow: UITableViewCell {

  @IBAction func tapThing(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var vc:UIViewController!

    // THIS DOESN'T WORK:
self.thingController!.pushViewController(storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thingDetail") as UIViewController, animated: true)            
  }

}
```

The error is "'feedRow' does not have a member named 'thingController'"

Since this is within **UITableViewCell**, it therefore doesn't include controls present in **UIViewController** that other examples show.

UPDATE: Per the answer, this was moved to the ***didSelectRowAtIndexPath*** section.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var goThing = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("thingDetail") as UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(goThing, animated:true, completion:nil)

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it in your view controller class where is your tableview in function didSelectRowAtIndexPath it should work.

Comment: That worked, and would be explain why I couldn't find a code sample for it. Thank you!